# Router Outlet not able to render the specific component content

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
    Welcome Screen
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

employee-search.component.html :

```
<h1 class="title">
    Employee Search
  </h1>
<p>Employee search screen</p>
```

When I remove h1 tag from app.component.html, I can only see "Employee search screen". If I don't remove it I can see "Welcome screen" and "Employee search screen" on GUI. Any how "Employee search" is not visible on browser in any condition.

Is there is any problem with my routing?

Comment: what is there in class - 'title'?

Comment: Edit your question to include the router module please

Comment: Put it in app.component.html not app.module.ts

Comment: Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-ujcuhw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It got solved by removing title class for h1 tag

Comment: Please add the css for the title class in your original question. Otherwise this is unhelpful.